# Runaway raycasting when it should only respond on click

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've created a script to add a new plane to a scene every time I click on an existing plane - the detection uses a raycaster. However, instead of waiting for a click, the script uncontrollably adds more and more planes to the scene with no clicks at all. What have I missed?

Thanks!

```js
var container, renderer, scene, camera;
var container = document.body;

var frustumSize = 1000;

var width, height;

var numRows = 4;
var numCols = 7;
var spacingSize = 300;

var raycaster;
var mouse;

var savedColor;

function init() {

    width = window.innerWidth;
    height = window.innerHeight;

    container = document.createElement( 'div' );
    document.body.appendChild( container );

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    renderer.setClearColor(0x000000);

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    var aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( frustumSize * aspect / - 2, frustumSize * aspect / 2, frustumSize / 2, frustumSize / - 2, 0, 2000 );
    // camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( width / - 2, width / 2, height / 2, height / - 2, 0, 2000 );
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();


    // set up grid of colored planes

    var startXPos = -((spacingSize*(numCols-1))/2);
    var startYPos = -((spacingSize*(numRows-1))/2);

    for ( var i = 0; i < numCols; i++ ) {
        var x = startXPos + (i*spacingSize);

        for ( var j = 0; j < numRows; j++ ) {
            var y = startYPos + (j*spacingSize);
            var z = -10 + (j * -1.0001);

            var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 50, 50 );
            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: new THREE.Color( Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random() ), side: THREE.DoubleSide} );
            var plane = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            plane.position.set( x, y, z );
            scene.add(plane);

        }
    }

    savedColor = null;

    raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
    mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

    document.addEventListener( 'click', onDocumentClick, false );

    var axesHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper( 100 );
    scene.add( axesHelper );

    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    scene.updateMatrixWorld();
    render();
    
}

function render() {

    // update the picking ray with the camera and mouse position
    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );

    // calculate objects intersecting the picking ray
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children );

    // calculate objects intersecting the picking ray
    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
        // console.log("yo!");
        for ( var i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++ ) {

            var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 60, 60 );
            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: new THREE.Color( 0xffff00 ), side: THREE.DoubleSide} );
            var plane = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            plane.position.set( getRandomBetween(-300,300), getRandomBetween(-300,300), -20 );
            scene.add(plane);
            // console.log("hey!");

            scene.updateMatrixWorld();

        }
    }

    renderer.render( scene, camera );
    requestAnimationFrame( render );
}

function getRandomBetween( min, max ) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}


function onDocumentClick( event ) {

    event.preventDefault();
    // calculate mouse position in normalized device coordinates
    // (-1 to +1) for both components
    // console.log("Oi!");
    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

}

init();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/106/three.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the initial position of `mouse` is (0, 0), which intersects with the `AxesHelper`.

change the inital position of `mouse` or remove `AxesHelper` or change the intersecting target to a specific group should resolve this.

Comment: Hi, thanks - I tried your edit and that did stop the initial cascade, but after the first click they all pile up as before. I'd like only one plane to appear per click. How can I fix this?

Comment: move away mouse after adding plane can fix that.